# getDynamicLink method not exposed by @ionic-native/firebase-dynamic-links plugin

Tags: firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase-dynamic-links, ionic5

I need to generate an invitation link that will deep-link to an Ionic app whether it is running in the background or not. Versions installed for the plugin

```
cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks 4.8.0
@ionic-native/firebase-dynamic-links 5.29.0
```

The [documentation for the Cordova plugin](https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks) lists a `getDynamicLink` method that seems to be the method that is supposed to be used to retrieve any pending deep links when the application is not running in the background.

```
cordova.plugins.firebase.dynamiclinks.getDynamicLink().then(function(data) {
    if (data) {
        console.log("Read dynamic link data on app start:", data);
    } else {
        console.log("App wasn't started from a dynamic link");
    }
});
```

Version 5.29.0 of the ionic-native wrapper do not expose this method. Is there any reason that this method is not being exposed?

[image]

I tested the `onDynamicLink` which works when the application is running, but as expected this method do not trigger when the application is not running and opened with a Firebase deep link. Is there another version of the plugin that exposes the `getDynamicLink` method? Or another way that the deep link can be retrieved when openening the application?

Comment: It seems like someone already added the missing method and that they submitted a merge request via GIT https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/pull/3567

Answer (score 0):

Ericgopak already added the missing method declaration and submitted a merge request via [GitHub](http://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/pull/3567)

Until the merge request is accepted the following steps can be followed to include the fix in your local repository

1. Clone the Ericgopak's repository with the `git clone --branch firebase-dynamic-links-missing-decl-getdynamiclink https://github.com/ericgopak/ionic-native.git`
2. Install RimRaf with `npm install rimraf --save-dev`
3. Build the repository with `npm run build`
4. Copy the `dist\@ionic-native\plugins\firebase-dynamic-links` to your projects `node_modules\@ionic-native` folder